How to Equitably Split the Expenses of a Trip Between Two Partners?

Hello everyone,
I have a question about how to equitably split the expenses of a trip between two partners. This is a problem posed by my logic professor, and despite our efforts, we do not fully understand the reasoning behind the correct calculation. Here are the details:

Partner A spent a total of €2081.89.
Partner B spent a total of €862.79.

They want to split the expenses fairly so that both pay the same total amount for the trip. They need help to determine how to achieve an equitable split.
Here is the approach A followed:

Calculate the total expenses:

€2081.89 + €862.79 = €2944.68

Divide the total expenses by two to find out how much each partner should pay:

€2944.68 / 2 = €1472.34

Calculate the difference between what each partner has paid and what they should pay:

Partner A has paid €2081.89 but should pay €1472.34.
    Partner B has paid €862.79 but should pay €1472.34.
The difference is:
€2081.89 - €1472.34 = €609.55
Therefore, Partner B should transfer €609.55 to Partner A to equalize the expenses.
However, B have another approach and are unsure of its correctness:

Divide what Partner A paid by 2:

€2081.89 / 2 = €1040.945

Subtract what Partner B spent:

€1040.945 - €862.79 = €178.155
According to this logic, Partner B should transfer €178.155 to Partner A.
Could you help us understand which reasoning is correct and why?
Thank you for your help.

I don't understand the logic in the second method.   Try it with simpler numbers.  Say $A$ paid $100$ and $B$ paid $50$.  Then, you'd have me divide $A$ by $0$, getting $50$, then subtract the $50$ that $B$ paid, getting $0$, so you'd say no transfer need happen?  But how is that fair?  $A$ paid twice as much as $B$ paid.  Am I missing something?

@lulu you mean divide $A$ by 2, agreed for the rest

@QuantumMechanic  Right, thanks.

How to understand which is correct: In each case, subtract from A's cost how much money A gets from B, and add to B's cost how much B gives to A. Are the two totals equal? That is what you are supposed to accomplish, so success! Are the two totals different? Then failure!
